# How to re-render specific view layers?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, render-layers, viewlayers

I have a scene split into several view layers. They are rendered separately and then put together in the compositor.

I would like to re-render only some specific view layers, not all of them. How can I do this in 2.8x?

Answer (score 7):

How about one at a time using "Render Single Layer" check box? Or simply deselect the "Use for Rendering" from the layers you don't want to re-render.

[image]

Comment: Render single layer works on a layer by layer basis. But I want to render several at once. Also, when I uncheck “Use for rendering” that layer becomes empty after rendering. As a result I cannot use it for further compositing